# We're on the same team or We're in the same team?

Tags: prepositions

I always thought "We're on the same team" was correct. And when I searched Google book, I was able to get way more results of 'on the same team'. 
But I heard someone says the second one, and now I'm a little confused. 
If both are correct, then what's the difference? 
It would be very helpful if you give me an example sentence as well.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to ELL. Is there any more context you can provide, e.g. what was the full sentence where *in the same team* was used? Was the person saying it a native speaker of English? And what is your locale?

Answer (score 2):

The only time I've heard "in a team" is when people are working together on a project at their job. "We're in a team that's developing software for that," that kind of thing. Even then, *on* is more common. But I've heard it both ways.

Answer (score 1):

You will always be on a team.  I have never heard "in the team" used.